# Functions $f:X\to X$ that commute with "almost no others"

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $X$ be an infinite set and let $\text{End}(X)$ be the set of all functions $f:X\to X$. For $f\in\text{End}(X)$ let $$\text{Com}(f) = \{g\in\text{End}(X): g\circ f = f \circ g\}.$$
Is there $f\in \text{End}(X)$ such that $\text{Com}(f) = \{\text{id}_X, f\}$?

If not, what is $\min\{|\text{Com}(f)|:f\in\text{End}(X)\}$, in terms of $|X|$?

Comment: The powers of f commute with f.

Comment: This paper by Bonatti, Crovisier, and Wilkinson https://doi.org/10.1007/s10240-009-0021-z shows that for (Baire-)generic C^1 diffeomorphisms of a compact manifold, the centralizer of f contains only the powers of f. See the paper's introduction for related results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope: since $f^2$ commutes with $f$, we should have either $f^2=\mathrm{id}_X$ or $f^2=f$, that is $f$ is either idempotent  or involutive. But on an infinite set it is easy to see these always have infinite commutators.

Comment: Thanks for this argument! It shows that $|\text{Com}(f)| \geq \aleph_0$ for all $f\in\text{End}(X)$. But it could still be that there is an uncountable set $X$ and $f:X\to X$ such that $|\text{Com}(f)| < |X|$, or does your argument exclude that?

Comment: Consider $X:=\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal, and define $f(\alpha)=\alpha+1$. Then as for $X=\mathbf{N}$ an element $g$ of $\text{End}(X)$ must be a $f^\alpha$, $\alpha\in\omega_1$. 

Because the addition of ordinals is not commutative we have $\alpha<\omega$. We obtain $|\text{Com{f}}|=|\omega|<|X|$.

Comment: @JoelAdler But why $g(n)=s+n$ does not commute with $f$ for _any_ $a\in\omega_1$? We have $g(f(n))=g(n+1)=a+n+1=(a+n)+1=f(g(n)$...

Comment: In fact it seems to me that even for $X=\omega^2$ there are continuum many maps commutating with $x\mapsto x+1$. Indeed, $f:\omega^2\to \omega^2$ decomposes into countably many invariant sets, i.e. the intervals $\{\omega\cdot k\le x< \omega\cdot (k+1)\} $, in each of them being isomorphic to $ f:\omega \to \omega $. Choosing $g$ to be either $f$ or $id$ on each of these intervals, one finds continuum many $g$ commutating with $f$.

Comment: Sorry, my argument is wrong.

Comment: What are the functions $\sin(x)$ commutes with?

Comment: @Joel: Since in this case for any $x$ the fiber $f^{-1}(x)$ is at most countable, so is the $f$-invariant set generated by $x$, $I(x):=\cup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f^{k}(x)$.
These sets make a partition of $\mathbb{R}$ in uncountably many classes. We can take $g$ to be either $f$ or $id$ on each of these classes, so I'd say there are $2^\mathbf{c}$  functions commuting with $f$.

Comment: (The class of x, I(x), is larger than the union I wrote, but still at most countable)

Comment: (the correct expression for $I(x)$ is $I(x):=\cup_{h\in\mathbb{N},k\in\mathbb{N}}f^{-h}(f^k(x))$, so any two $I(x)$ and $I(x')$ either coincide or are disjoint).

Answer (score 4):

Let $X:=\mathbf{N}$ and $f:X\rightarrow X$ be defined by $f(n)=n+1$, and let $g:X\rightarrow X$ commute with $f$.

We have $g(n+1)=g(f(n))=f(g(n))=g(n)+1$ for all $n\in X$. Thus, with $g(0)=a$ we obtain $g(n)=a+n=f^a(n)$, which means that the powers of $f$ are the only elements of $\text{End}(X)$ commuting with $f$.

Thus $|\text{Com(f)}|=|\mathbf{N}|=|X|$.

Comment: This is nice, and this is maybe the minimum cardinality, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks! So for this particular $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ you prove that $\text{Com}(f)$ is infinite - but is there maybe another $f_0:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $\text{Com}(f_0)$ is finite? -- Oh ok - I just saw Pietro Majer's input on this!